# How do you raise an exception inside an except block without exception chaining in a way that's compatible with both Python 2 and 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

In Python 2.7, the following will only print one traceback, from the exception raised in the `except` block:

```
try:
   1/0
except ZeroDivisionError:
   raise Exception("Error!")
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
Exception: Error!
```

However in Python 3 there is exception chaining. Here is the output for the same code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
Exception: Error!
```

I need to write some code that is compatible with both Python 2.7 and Python 3, and I need for there to be *no exception chaining* when the exception is raised inside that `except` block. So that the output will be what you see above when that code is executed in Python 2.7.

The one possible solution I've found is `raise_from`, included in the `six` module:

```
from six import raise_from
try:
   1/0
except ZeroDivisionError:
   raise_from(Exception("Error!"), None)
```

However, it adds an extra line for `raise_from` to the traceback that I'd like to avoid:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
Exception: Error!
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The question isnt really clear, are you asking for why it is giving an error? or why the error is chaning.

Comment: While this is certainly *possible*, it won't necessarily be simple – *why* go all the way to suppress a cause you don't care about, or even just a single traceback layer?

Comment: Can I be the oddball who says you should handle the exception? Especially if you just don't like the way python's default handlers report it.

Comment: @KennyOstrom I am handling the exception. That's why I don't want it included in the traceback. The purpose here is to raise custom, user-facing exceptions for my module (which is an API), some of which happen when other exceptions are raised. I don't want the user to see the internal traceback being raised because it's irrelevant to them and only serves to make the traceback needlessly more verbose and complicated.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'm trying to avoid adding `raise_from` to the exception just for cleanliness. But if there's no good way to avoid that -- and it rather looks like there isn't -- then I can live with that. No need to let the perfect be the enemy of good, and all that.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Do you have python 3.9? I'm looking at the traceback module. There's also a __suppress_context__ attribute, but I'm trying to avoid internals that might change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following produces identical output on py2.7.13 and py3.9.2, if you call it with the full path. (If you use a relative path, py3 expands it, but py2 does not.)

```
try:
    1/0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    internal = Exception("Error!")
    internal.__suppress_context__ = True
    raise internal
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "b:\development\python\so.py", line 6, in 
> raise internal
> Exception: Error!

I was hoping to avoid internal attributes that might change, but __suppress_context__ is documented https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html

Answer (score 1):

Use a `finally` block to discard the context after the exception was raised:

```py
try:
   1/0
except ZeroDivisionError:
   # store exception to allow modifying it
   exc = Exception("Error!")
   try:
       raise exc
   finally:
       # context has been set here already – discard it
       exc.__context__ = None
```

This also works in Python2 for any proper exception, i.e. those derived from `BaseException`.